# How can I map data points to OpenStreetMap (OSM) line data?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

my goal is to filter measuring points of vehicles by mapping them to streets.
So I could filter out all the false data located in fields and rivers and so on.

I imported my data into a PostGIS database and can work fine with my Point data.
I also imported the part of OSM that i need into a PostGIS table.

Is using ST_DWithin the right way? I did use that to only show points in a certain distance to another point.

How can I now get only these points that are located, let's say 20 metres around the OSM lines?

**EDIT1:**

I have been trying to first filter the data and the OSM line data to a circle area of 5km and then using ST_DWithin to get the mapping:

```
WITH
    Data as
    ( SELECT gid,geom FROM schema1.data AS Mp
        WHERE Mp.id=14
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM schema1.base As Base
            WHERE Base."ID"=14
            AND st_covers(st_makeenvelope(-180, -90, 180, 90, 4326), Mp.geom)
            AND ST_DWithin(Mp.geom::geography, Base.geom::geography, 5000)
            )
    ),
    Line As
    ( SELECT * FROM public.planet_osm_line As Line
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM schema1.base As Base
            WHERE Base."ID"=14
            AND ST_DWithin(Line.way::geography, Base.geom::geography, 5000)
            AND Line.highway='motorway'
            )
    )
SELECT
    Data.*
FROM
    Data, Line
WHERE
    st_covers(st_makeenvelope(-180, -90, 180, 90, 4326), Data.geom)
    AND ST_DWithin(Data.geom::geography, Line.way::geography, 20);
```

Unfortunately "Data" still consists of 5014309 and "Line" of  5686 rows.
What can I improve in my query to speed up things here?

If i understand the query execution correctly, postresql is trying to build a temporary table and thus joining Data and Line to 5014309*5686 rows...

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem. I have points that represent vehicles and would like to get the closest road to within some error tolerance.

In my case, the data I have is in SRID 900913 while the submitted points are lat,lng.

Here's the query that's working for me:

```
SELECT 
     osm_id, 
     name, 
     ST_XMin(line.way), 
     ST_XMax(line.way), 
     ST_Distance(line.way, st_transform(
         st_setsrid(st_makepoint(36.768676, -1.289927), 4326),
         900913)) as distance 
FROM 
     line 
WHERE 
     ST_DWithin(line.way, 
                st_transform(
                   st_setsrid(st_makepoint(36.768676, -1.289927), 4326),
                   900913),
                5);


-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------
osm_id   | 25060263
name     | Gitanga Road
st_xmin  | 4093024.51
st_xmax  | 4093669.13
distance | 0.993252319680161
```